# HTML won't display 2 images

Tags: html

I want to display 2 images on the same row like this:

```
Image  Same Text  Image
```

If I put one image it works, but if I put both of them I get 404.
I think I am doing something wrong in the code I don't have much experience with HTML and don't know what I am missing.
The files are in same folder.
Here is the code:

```
<td colspan="8" >
<h1>
<img src="/home/apps/myapp/dynamic/img/myimage1.png" style="float:left; " alt="This is my mage" height="130" width="455">
<b>Same text</b>
<img src="/home/apps/myapp/dynamic/img/myimage2.png" style="float:right; vertical-align:middle;" alt="My second image" height="130" width="454"></h1>
</td>
```

Comment: `<<img src=...` <-- is this really what you have in your HTML file?  It looks like a big typo to me.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want both images to be wrapped in a `h1`?  
And that table, are you using it for tabular data or layout purposes?

Comment: No, it just <img src = ... I copy paste wrong when editing the question

Comment: @domsson layout purposes

Comment: If you receive a 404 error the path to your image must be incorrect.

Comment: @Christian in that case you might want to avoid using a table. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html) for some reasons.

Comment: Looks like incorrect image path... please check if the path is correct.

Comment: I checked it and it's correct. If I display only one image it works. But if give the same path to both of them it returns 2 404

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do by creating a nested table.

```
<td>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>Image 1</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Image 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

or you can do by creating `div` with `float` attributes. Do image1 and text to `float:left;` and image2 to `float:right`.

Comment: I think the issue isn't the placement (at least not yet), but rather the 404 error he gets.

Comment: As per his question statement, issue is with placement as he is not good in HTML.

Comment: Actually, it reads _"If I put one image it works, but if I put both of them I get 404."_ and doesn't mention any issues with placement. However, OP accepted this answer, so apparently you are right. Me, I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

simply you can use bootstrap..
divide the page into 2 halves using col-md-6 and put your data in its individual divs

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="/path1">
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <img src="/path2">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra start tag in your code, which is giving the error.

The Problem:

```
<<img src="/home/apps/myapp/dynamic/img/myimage2.png" 
style="float:right; vertical-align:middle;" alt="My second image" 
height="130" width="454"></h1>
```

The Solution

```
<img src="/home/apps/myapp/dynamic/img/myimage2.png" 
style="float:right; vertical-align:middle;" alt="My second image" 
height="130" width="454"></h1>
```

Comment: That wouldn't cause a 404 error. The extra `<` would just be interpreted as a text node.

Comment: @Turnip, yes you are right. Actually, such HTML error will not give 404 error. For that more clarity on the requirement or test case is needed.